# How to detect implicit method to delegate conversion in Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

So id like to find places where method group id implcitly cast to delegate like:

```
EventHandler a = method;
```

and distinguish them from explicit delegate creation

```
EventHandler a = new EventHandler(method);
```

Type info and conversion looks completely the same for both of these. Is there a way to do it using semantic model without traversing tree and trying to find a parent new object expression?

Comment: I think you will need to use the `SyntaxWalker` and look for a missing new when assigning to a `delegate`.

Comment: How are you finding the nodes that you're going to pass to the `SemanticModel` in the first place?

Comment: For example every simple name node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These places could be found out roughly by walking binary expression nodes and looking on Right expression conversion:

```
void VisitBinaryExpression(BinaryExpressionSyntax binaryExpression)
{
   var conversion = semanticModel.GetConversion(binaryExpression.Right);
   if (conversion.IsMethodGroup)
   {

   }
}
```

It doesn't look very reliable but that's what I found out so far.

Comment: Hm, yes, but in this case you only need to visit BinaryExpression nodes

Comment: As far as I know, only writing visitor for one type of node doesn't prevent traversing all the tree.
btw, if you want to use visitors, I guess assignment expression might be a better node to visit.