# Disable implicit conversion of third party classes in C# without writing wrappers?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I use an engine which got **Vector3** and **Vector2** classes.

However there are regular issues by **accidentally passing** a **Vector2** to a **method which needs a Vector3**.

Currently it's **automatically converted** to a Vector3 of (x, y, 0). After I experience runtime issues it always takes some time to I find these trivial causes...

Is it possible to somehow **block the implicit conversion** between these two third party classes so I can detect these problems at compile time?

Currently my only idea is to **write wrappers** and replace every usage of Vector3 and Vector2 with them.

But it seems tedious. **Is there any other way?**

Comment: There's no way to prevent this from happening, it's a basic C# feature

Comment: I assume this is about Unity?  Seems there's an [old discussion](https://forum.unity.com/threads/implicit-conversion-between-vector2-and-vector3.621676/) about this behavior.  But if you disagree with a 3rd party API design (which is reasonable here), you can't hack it to suit your purposes.

Comment: You could write a Roslyn code-analyzer that raises a warning or message whenever implicit conversion is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a custom code analyzer and configure it to cause a compile-time error whenever this implicit conversion happens in your code.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix for a tutorial.

If you do this, you could also put that analyzer into a Nuget package so other people using the same third-party library can benefit from the work you've done.

Comment: I had a go on Roslyn and it all seemed fun at first, but I've got stuck. If you have some spare time, could you lend me a hand? :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71264254/roslyn-analyzer-to-detect-all-kinds-of-implicit-conversions

Comment: @Tudvari: I haven't written a Roslyn analyzer myself (still on my bucket list), but here are some links I found that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50969589/120955 https://www.meziantou.net/working-with-types-in-a-roslyn-analyzer.htm#get-the-type-of-a-sy-c103e6 https://stackoverflow.com/q/39396441/120955 https://stackoverflow.com/a/26773291/120955 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.conversion.isimplicit?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.1.0#microsoft-codeanalysis-csharp-conversion-isimplicit https://github.com/binki/OhNoPub.ImplicitCastAnalyzer

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that Vector3 class has this code:

```
public static implicit operator Vector3(Vector2 vector) => new Vector3(vector.x, vector.y, 0);
```

Unfortunately, you cannot block the conversion (C# built-in feature). Honestly, it is a poor design choice made by the Engine designers...

You can only create your own wrappers to overcome this issue.

```
public class Vector2Ex {
  public Vector2 vector2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: "pass-through" wrappers over a single value (be it a reference-type or value-type) with no additional state of their own should generally be `readonly struct` instead of `class` though.

Comment: I started replacing everything with wrapper classes but everything became a mess. So I think I'll go with @StriplingWarrior's answer and using a code analyzer I will detect all implicit conversions.