# Roslyn analyzer to detect all kinds of implicit conversions?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I need a code analyzer which **warns me about every implicit cast/conversion** like when assigning a variable or passing an argument to method.

I started a tutorial series on Roslyn but it's still huge and I can't find the solution.

I tried the code below but it doesn't seem to work.

I guess I have to analyze the code semantically instead of syntactically. I tried it but got lost in the huge amount of properties, methods, etc. and **don't know how could I find implicit conversions in the model.**

```
context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeNodeArgument, SyntaxKind.Argument);
context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeNodeExpressionStatement, SyntaxKind.ExpressionStatement);

private void AnalyzeNodeArgument(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
{
    var arg = (ArgumentSyntax)context.Node;
    var typeInfo = context.SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo(arg);
    var convertedImplicitly = !SymbolEqualityComparer.Default.Equals(typeInfo.Type, typeInfo.ConvertedType);
    if (convertedImplicitly)
    {
        context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, context.Node.GetLocation(), new string[1] { "Asd" }));
    }
}

private void AnalyzeNodeExpressionStatement(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
{
    var expressionStatement = (ExpressionStatementSyntax)context.Node;
    var typeInfo = context.SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo(expressionStatement);
    var convertedImplicitly = !SymbolEqualityComparer.Default.Equals(typeInfo.Type, typeInfo.ConvertedType);
    if (convertedImplicitly)
    {
        context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, context.Node.GetLocation(), new string[1] { "Bsd" }));
    }
}
```

This is the code I tried it on, where **Vector3 and Vector2 converted to each other implicitly**. *(I use the Unity3D engine)*

But no error, warning, or anything is shown, everything compiles perfectly. (The only hint shown is that variable "a" is unused.)

```
void Update()
{
    Vector2 a = Vector3.zero;
    var b = Vector2.zero;
    Asd(b);
}

void Asd(Vector3 a)
{
    print(a.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `context.RegisterOperationAction(AnalyzeConversionOperation, OperationKind.Conversion)`, then check for `operation.IsImplicit` inside `AnalyzeConversionOperation`? You may want to check the parent operation as well. For example `throw null` produces conversion operation but you might not want to consider it.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I've just tried but it isn't triggered. I do this: context.RegisterOperationAction(AnalyzeConversionOperation, OperationKind.Conversion); And in the method: 
   if (context.Operation.IsImplicit || context.Operation.Parent.IsImplicit)
   {
    context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, null, new string[1] { "Asd" }));
   }

Comment: You need to write a test and see if `AnalyzeConversionOperation` is hit, and if so where things go wrong.